# How to map True and False to 'Yes' and 'No' in a pandas data frame for columns of dtype bool only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, boolean

I have a `pandas` data frame (v 0.20.3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'coname1': ['Apple','Yahoo'], 'coname2':['Apple', 'Google']})
df['eq'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['coname1'] == row['coname2'], axis=1).astype(bool)

   coname1 coname2     eq
0    Apple   Apple   True
1    Yahoo  Google  False
```

If I would like to replace `True/False` to `'Yes'/'No'`, I could run this:

```
df.replace({
                True: 'Yes',
                False: 'No'
            })

   coname1 coname2   eq
0    Apple   Apple  Yes
1    Yahoo  Google   No
```

Which seems to get the job done. However, if a data frame is just one row with a value of `0/1` in a column, it will be also replaced as it's being treated as Boolean.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'coname1': [1], 'coname2':['Google'], 'coname3':[777]})
df1['eq'] = True

   coname1 coname2  coname3    eq
0        1  Google      777  True

df1.replace({
                True: 'Yes',
                False: 'No'
            })

  coname1 coname2 coname3   eq
0     Yes  Google     777  Yes
```

I would like to map `True/False` to `Yes/No` for all columns in the data frame that are of `dtype` `bool`.

**How do I tell `pandas` to run map True/False to arbitrary strings only for the columns that are of `dtype` `bool` without explicitly specifying the names of columns as I may not know them in advance?**

Comment: do you want this on all columns that are of dtype bool or just the column eq?

Comment: @jacoblaw, I would like to map `True/False` to `Yes/No` for all columns in the data frame that are of `dtype` `bool`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the dtypes attribute to check if the column is boolean and filter based on that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['x', 'y'], 
                   'C': [True, False], 'D': [False, True]})

df
Out: 
   A  B      C      D
0  0  x   True  False
1  1  y  False   True

bool_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == 'bool']

df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})

df
Out: 
   A  B    C    D
0  0  x  Yes   No
1  1  y   No  Yes
```

I think the fastest way would be to use map in a loop though:

```
for col in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'bool']:
    df[col] = df[col].map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Comment: Seems a much better approach than mine (+1), I'm not sure but `.replace` should be faster than `.applymap`

Comment: golf version `df.replace({c: {True: 'Yes', False: 'No'} for c in df.select_dtypes([bool])})`

Comment: Thanks for the options, brilliant. Have just found out that this could also work - `df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'bool'] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'bool'].replace({
                True:
                'Yes',
                False:
                'No'
            })`. What do you say about this one?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Yes that would also work quite nice. The only thing I would change in that is to save `df.dtypes == 'bool'`  to a variable in order not to repeat the same thing again.

Comment: @piRSquared That's actually quite good (I always forget that replace can take column names as keys). I think `select_dtypes` creates unnecessary copies though. If I would be able to operate on the view that would be OK but in its current state comparing dtypes seems like a better option.

Comment: I finally threw my hat in the ring

Answer (score 3):

A nice workaround is to create a function that first checks if the element is of type bool or not, and then use `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'coname1': [1], 'coname2':['Google'], 'coname3':[777]})
df1['eq'] = True

def bool2yes(boolean):
    if isinstance(boolean, bool):
        if boolean == True:
            return "Yes"
        else:
            return "No"
    else:
        return boolean

>>> df1.applymap(bool2yes)
   coname1 coname2  coname3   eq
0        1  Google      777  Yes
```

Answer (score 3):

My Take

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.eq(bool)]
vals = np.column_stack([df[c].values for c in cols])

df[cols] = np.array(['No', 'Yes'])[vals.astype(int)]

df

   A  B    C    D
0  0  x  Yes   No
1  1  y   No  Yes
```